# Scope on has_many, :through relationship with array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following associations:

```
#models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :locations, through :relationships
end

#models/relationship.rb
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :location
end

#models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :contacts, through: :relationships
end
```

What I want to do is create a scope that finds all the `contacts` associated to an array of `location` ids.

I attempted this scope but it wasn't working.  It joins the tables right, but the array I am passing in appears to be causing some trouble. Something appears to be wrong with my syntax within the `where` clause.

```
#models/Contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :by_locations, ->(ids_ary){joins(relationships: :location).where("locations.id IN ?", ids_ary)}
end
```

Comment: Is it 'scope' in the code or 'scoop'?

Comment: @nik it is `scope`, I had a typo here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, you can also rewrite your query to use a hash instead:

```
scope :by_locations, ->(ids_ary) { joins(relationships: :location).where("locations.id" => ids_ary) }
```

Comment: Thank you!  The hash syntax still gets me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add parenthesis around the question mark:

```
scope :by_locations, ->(ids_ary){joins(relationships: :location).where("locations.id IN (?)", ids_ary)}
```